# How to return existing matching record for Django CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I use a regular `generic.edit.CreateView` of `Django` to create an object according to user input. The `MyModel` has an `UniqueConstrait` so the creation would fail if the new object happens to match an existing one.

However, instead of telling users that creation fails due to duplicate records, I would like to simply return the existing object since this is what users want. I tried to override

```py
    def save(self, commit=True):
        return MyModel.get_or_create(value=self.cleaned_data['value'])[0]
```

but this does not work because `form._post_clean` will call [`form.instance.full_clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0c1518ee429b01c145cf5b34eab01b0b92f8c246/django/forms/models.py#LL494C7-L494C7) with its default `validate_constraints=True`, so an error will return during form validation.

Essentially I am looking for a `GetOrCreateView` but I am not sure what is a clean way to achieve this (other than maybe overriding `form._full_clean`). Note that I am not looking for a `UpdateView` because we do not know in advance which existing object will be returned.

**Edit**: After struggling with the validation issue for a very long time, I finally abandoned `CreateView` and resorted to a simpler `FormView`. The `FormView` will simply get all the user input I need, before calling `get_or_create(form.cleaned_data[...])` in `form_valid(self, form)`.

Comment: What's wrong with `.exist()`? I think you can use it by doing: `existing_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=pk).exist()` then you can pass an error message.

Comment: I do not have a `pk` to get the `existing_object`. The scenario is that the user is creating an object by entering a name in a form backed by a `CreateView`, the name happens to clash with an existing object so the `CreateView` is supposed to return an existing object matching the user's input, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the behavior you described, where instead of raising an error for duplicate records, you want to return the existing object, Here's an example of how you can implement it:

```
class CreateObjectOfMyModel(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['value']

    def get_form(self, form_class=None): 
        form = super().get_form(form_class) 
        value = form.data.get('value')
        form.fields['value'].queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(value=value)
        return form
```

The `get_form` method is `overridden` in this class base view, It calls the `get_form` method using `super().get_form(form_class)` to get the base form object. Then the `value` field of the form to filter out duplicate records, I have also added a line to retrieve the entered value from the form data using `form.data.get('value')`. I hope it works.

Comment: I would argue that `form_valid` will never be called if there exists duplicate record, since a unique validation error will be raised in form validation and thus `form_invalid` gets called instead. Instead, one should override `post` method.

Comment: You're correct. The `form_invalid` method will be called instead of `form_valid`. Check my answer again.

Comment: This will not work either because `is_valid()` will call `self.errors`, `self.full_clean()`, `self._post_clean()`, `self.instance.full_clean()` and return `False` due to the constraint on the model. I think the root problem is that django (4.2) allows bypassing `validate_unique`, but does not allow bypassing `validate_constraints` of `models.base.Model.full_clean()`, so form validation will always fail in this particular example (unless `_post_clean` is overriden).

Comment: You're correct in your analysis. The code I provided will not work as intended due to the way Django's [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/validation/) Check my answer again, I hope it would work.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution might work for simple cases but in my real application user inputs from multiple fields need to go through a series of `clean_` calls before they are used to create an object, so it is awkward to override `get_form` this way.

Comment: I chatted with a Django expert and the recommendation I got is to avoid the `UniqueConstraint` during `clean()`. If the unique field is a derived one, it could be left un-cleaned and handled at the `save` stage. If the field is directly user-inputted, it could be checked and changed (e.g. add an unique suffix) to pass validation, before changing back during `save`.